# How to redirect c3p0 log messages to my application log file

Tags: c3p0

I have a standalone java application. I have decided to use c3p0 for connection pooling. Currently I am using java.util.logging.Logger for logging application messages. jdk1.6 is being used. All the application log messages are being written to a file /tmp/app.log. How do I make sure that c3p0 also logs it's messages to that file. I have tried adding the following in c3p0.properties.

com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=java.util.logging.Logger

But If I run the application I see the following message and app.log does not contain any c3p0 log.

Tried without success to load the following MLog classes:
    java.util.logging.Logger
Nov 11, 2011 2:12:23 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog 
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [log4j-over-slf4j](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22log4j-over-slf4j%22), MLog will log to that "fake" log4j, which will in turn be slf4j, then you can use [slf4j-jdk14](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22slf4j-jdk14%22) so that slf4j sends logs to java.util.logging.

EDIT: Didn't realize I had answered two questions about this. The other one was updated about a year after I answered it, as JBoss decided to add some utterly stupid crap into their logger. See [answer 14932944](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932944) to [question 6852916](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852916). Basically, you need to create an empty class "org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy" to override the dumbness, and then you can go back to happily using SLF4J.

Comment: I can't believe both your answer and the original question didn't get loads of upvotes! Logging is one of the most irritating things about Java development.